# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /u01/app/webapps/out/pj/Create.xlsx

Tags: java, excel, file, filenotfoundexception, fileoutputstream

I am trying to Compare last modified date of two excel files and replace the old file with new file.

> **In Scenario :** When there is no file in the first place, so the code copies the file to that location and later reads it.
>
> **Issue is :** It throws a `FileNotFound exception` when the excel file is not present on the server,even after writing the file to the
>   server(via code),but the file is not seen on the server. It works on
>   my machine`(windows)`,but fails when deployed on server.

Again, it works like charm when the file is present on the server,while the old is being replaced by the new file.

Can you please help and explain on why its failing in the above scenario,and only on server ?

```
if(row.getValue("fileType").toString().equals("xlsx")&&checkindatefolder.after(localdate))
                {
                messagelist.add("we are going to get the replace file in the server");


            InputStream inp=folder.getFile();
            ZipInputStream izs = new ZipInputStream(inp);
            ZipEntry e = null;
            while ((e = izs.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                System.out.println("e.isDirectory(): "+e.isDirectory());
            if (!e.isDirectory()) {
                    filename=e.getName();
                    System.out.println("filename: "+filename);
                    FileOutputStream os=new FileOutputStream("path"+e.getName());
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int    read=0;
                    System.out.println("writing to file");
                    while ((read=izs.read(buffer))> 0) {
                        System.out.println("1111");
                        os.write(buffer,0,read);
                    }
                    System.out.println("writing to file complete");
                    inp.close();
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: FileOutputStream is waiting a path to a file as parameter: `new FileOutputStream(<PATH_TO_FILE>);`

Comment: I have hard coded the path as - private String path = "/u01/app/webapps/out/pj/"; and it that is the case it shouldnt be working on the second scenario where the file is present right ?

Comment: Is this windows or linux path ?

Comment: This is a linux path. but while using windows, i have used another path with '//'.

Answer (score 0):

Do all parts of the path exist?

So in your example:

```
/u01/app/webapps/out/pj/Create.xlsx
```

Do all subdirectories exist?

```
/u01/app/webapps/out/pj
```

If not, than trying to write there might fail with a `FileNotFoundException`.

You should create the directories with `Files.creatDirectories(Path)` first.

Comment: Yes, all subdirectories exist and for the same reason the other scenario works. The new file replaces the old file.

Comment: @naRen What OS is running on your server?

Comment: Server is running on Red Hat 4.1.2-52 linux

Comment: @naRen Does the process, that is running your code, have access to that directory?

Comment: Yes.. we are able to read and write a new file to the directory, but only if the older version is present there. It only fails when there is no file earlier.

Comment: According to the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) it is filesystem dependend, if the FileOutputStream can create new files. My suggestion would be to create an empty file first using [File#createNewFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) and then open the stream to write to it.